# Postgresql select join sort by count

Tags: postgresql

I have two tables.

Goods:

```
                          Table "public.goods"
     Column      |           Type           |         Modifiers         
-----------------+--------------------------+---------------------------
 goods_id        | character varying        | not null
 goods_owner_id  | character varying        | not null
```

Sellers:

```
                          Table "public.sellers"
     Column      |           Type           |         Modifiers         
-----------------+--------------------------+---------------------------
 sellers_id      | character varying        | not null
 sellers_name    | character varying        | not null
```

How to make a request that will show sellers with the most quantity of goods?
Thank you.

Comment: Does `public.goods` table has foreign key constraint that references `sellers_id` column of `public.sellers`?

Comment: There are no such restrictions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is sql query:

```
SELECT sellers.sellers_id 
    FROM goods JOIN sellers ON goods.goods_owner_id = sellers.sellers_id
    GROUP BY sellers.sellers_id
    ORDER BY COUNT(goods.goods_id) DESC 
    LIMIT 1
```